# Gravity Fed Plumbing System - question on connecting pieces

Tags: plumbing, water, shower

I've got a 55" water barrel with the fixed lid and I want to prepare a small plumbing system that ideally uses gravity to provide the water pressure with one small caveat.

I would like a bronze or stainless steel spigot that I can install onto the barrel, and I would like it to have a standard garden hose end. This is the easy part and I have identified this model that I like:

[image: The specific water spigot I like to install on the 55 gallon barrel]

From this spigot I know I can thread a water hose to it, but from there I get a bit lost.

I would like to create a PVC system that would feed a sink, a toilet, and, our Coleman Hot Water On Demand with Shower head. The Coleman Water Heater has a pump that I would like to use to make sure we have enough water pressure, but the pump's intake has an odd size, and even if I hooked it straight up to a garden hose, I don't think it would fit.

Here's a stock photo of the pump that came with the water heater:
[image]

I believe the pump *can* be submerged, but I would like to hook straight up to it. I'm just not sure what the thing is called that would have threads that I could attach this pump to from our barrel > spigot > hose > ???? > water heater pump.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Since you don't include a model number or link to the product, it's going to be up to you to wander the aisle at your local plumbing supply place (be it big-box or specialty store) until you find the pieces that will fill in the `???` for you. It may take more than one piece, but eventually, you'll get from Garden Hose Thread to "pump thread".

Comment: The pump looks like it has quick dis/connects.  Those ends are push onto male adapters that can be screwed onto garden hoses/faucets

Comment: Surprise that the male ends were not sent also.  Not like a company would go under with sending them.

Comment: Please don't cross-post verbatim copy/pastes to different forums. As you can see, [your other post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/252808/gravity-fed-plumbing-system-specific-requirement) was migrated from [outdoors.se] here because it's appropriate here. You've got enough rep to jump into chat to see if a question would be appropriate at a particular site if you can't sort it out from the [help].

Answer (score 0):

As an indirect answer to your question, adapters of almost any kind can be found at hardware stores. Most fittings are available in brass and pvc - either might work for your use case. It's extremely helpful to bring the connectors you have with you to the store, so you can test-fit while you browse.

Some standards besides garden hose thread (NH) are tapered pipe (NPT), compression, flare, and barb. You can find adapters from virtually any of these to virtually any other; and if those aren't readily available locally, use two adapter fittings that thread to each other. Pay close attention to diameters, as well as whether they're inside (ID) or outside (OD) for fittings and tubing. Also it should go without saying, but use as few fittings as you can.

Source: I have been homebrewing for a number of years, which overlaps with DIY custom plumbing. Custom connections made with 1/4 turn ball valves and hose barbs are very common in homebrew.